# I can't resize/partition my disk in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am new to Ubuntu. A week ago I installed Ubuntu and by mistake I installed it in the Windows partition. What I did was that I deleted all the files from Windows and only installed Ubuntu 14.04.

Everything has been OK since then but I realised that there are almost no games to play in Linux, so I want to dual boot my computer because I still want to use Ubuntu.

I can't resize my disk, and I don't know why.

Ah, by the way my computer is a Sony Vaio (I don't know the ID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't resize or otherwise edit a mounted partition, and if you're working from inside Ubuntu (rather than, say, from a Live CD or USB), the partition Ubuntu is installed to is mounted.  Reboot from a Live medium, and you'll be able to do all the resizing and repartitioning you need.

Be careful, you already know why you should back up first!

Comment: What does "Reboot form a Live medium" mean? i'm not so professional as you! thanks for the answer by the way

Comment: Just insert the CD/DVD/USB device you used to install Ubuntu, reboot from this drive, and when it is ready, chose "Try Ubuntu" instead of "Install Ubuntu". You have a (almost) fully functional system that does not run/depend from your hard disk. It will only do not save any files or settings of the live session.